# Need regular expression for the RTSP

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have no deep knowledge about regex. need help!

I have the following rtsp and need to separate it

```
rtsp://user:password@google.com:554/ISAPI/streaming/channels/102
```

and the following regex

```
(rtsp):\/\/(?:([^\s^@\/]+?)[@])?([^\s\/:]+)(?:[:]([0-9]+))?([/\s(.*)])
```

Result in 101regex

```
Full match  rtsp://user:password@google.com:554/
Group 1.    rtsp
Group 2.    user:password
Group 3.    google.com
Group 4.    554
Group 5.    /
```

1. In the regex I cannot allow the @ character in the username and password (group 2).
2. Still in group two the rtsp may not have a username and password and then the group would be empty. Ex: rtsp://google.com:554/ISAPI/streaming/channels/102
3. And finally in group 5 I need the rest of the rtsp. Ex: /ISAPI/streaming/channels/102

Comment: You mention a regex, could you please add it to the question body?

Comment: had forgotten, I added

Comment: Do you need `/(rtsp):\/\/(?:([^\s@\/]+)@)?([^\s\/:]+)(?::([0-9]+))?(?:\/(.*))?/`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ADNLpe/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think you are right :-) , I read `the rtsp may not have a username and password` as it should not be empty but I think it can be.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's great!!! but no user or password I cannot allow the @ character

Comment: What do you mean then? That the URL with `@` in it should not be matched? `(rtsp):\/\/([^\s@\/]+)@([^\s\/:]+)(?::([0-9]+))?(?:\/(.*))?`?

Comment: Inside the url has the user and password, they could not contain @

Answer (score 0):

It group 2 for the username:pasword can not be empty, you can omit the optional non capturing group around it `(?:...)?`

The negated character class does not have to be non greedy `[^\s@/]+` as it can not pass the `@` char. (Note that `[^\s^@\/]` will also not allow to match the `^` and the `/`)

If you want to match the "rest" in group 5, you can match the `/` followed by any char 0+ times `(\/.*)`

You don't have to use square brackets for `@` and `:`

```
(rtsp):\/\/([^\s@/]+)@([^\s/:]+)(?::([0-9]+))?(\/.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bnMZEb/1)